# CSS Body background image fixed

Tags: html, css

How do you get a Body Background image in CSS to stay fixed even as you scroll to content off the page. I've put a fiddle up: http://jsfiddle.net/eSALE/7/

This is my current CSS body code:

```
body { 
background: url('http://s22.postimg.org/u9jjshrfl/nature_desktop_background_wallpapers.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

See the fiddle for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
background-color: #333;
```

under 'html, body {}' at the beginning of your CSS Style sheet.

Edit: All you really need to do is remove the top HTML in your stylesheet so that the style reads:

```
body {
    background #333;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this is done as a fallback if the background image cannot be displayed.

Comment: The fallback `background-color` is really needed in case the background image is not available, removing so is OK but it should be moved to the style for the `body` only. It's interesting (and a little weird) that the problem is caused by setting the `background-color` for the `html` tag? But not really, by trial and error, I've found that it requires 2 conditions: **both** the `html` and `body` have `height` set to `100%` and the `html` has `background-color` set, weird.

Comment: King, you're right, I should have mentioned that.  I have never seen a background-color set for html before.

Comment: This absolutely crazy. But it was my fault for putting background-color on the html tag. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the background image from body tag and add to site-wrapper

```
.site-wrapper {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
      min-height: 100%;
      background: url('http://s22.postimg.org/u9jjshrfl/nature_desktop_background_wallpapers.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/eSALE/9/)

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution of the problum

```
 body{ 
   background: url('http://s22.postimg.org/u9jjshrfl/nature_desktop_background_wallpapers.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;

    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mehar/yej2n/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick..........

```
    html {
         background: url('http://s22.postimg.org/u9jjshrfl/nature_desktop_background_wallpapers.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Here's the updated fiddle......

http://jsfiddle.net/xcKs9/1/